# SQL Server vs MySQL: CONTAINS(*,'FORMSOF(THESAURUS,word)')

Tags: mysql, sql-server, full-text-search, stemming, thesaurus

I am shocked.

I spent past 3-4 days figuring out how I could implement stemming (and synonyms searches) in mysql when I see in SQL Server the query is incredibly easly:

```
Select * from tab where CONTAINS(*,'FORMSOF(THESAURUS,word)')
```

Is possibile on MySql there isn't anything like that?

Comment: Strange as it may seem, free `MySQL` has less features than commercial `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 5):

No, `MySQL` does not support matching against a user-provided thesaurus.

You can use an external `FULLTEXT` engine like Sphinx which [supports](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology) morphology rules, has several stemmers and thesauri built in and allows pluggable ones.

Comment: unfortunaly sphnix doens't seem to have both of them. On forum a user said: stemming only works on english words and there aren't any built-in thesaurus. Source: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=6832 (read last 3-4 posts)